# Using mean function in MATLAB yielding different results

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have just recently started using MATLAB as it's pretty good for machine learning and the like.

Currently, I am working on some type of classification which is pretty long-winded and complicated if I tried to explain everything I am trying to accomplish therefore I will just state the exact code giving me problems.

So, I am given a 1010 x 1764 `single` type matrix by some function. say the matrix is called `train_examples_2_2` as you can see on the right-hand side of the screenshot below.

[image]

As you can also see from the screenshot above (on the right-hand side), the calls to  `mean` and `std`:

```
mean = mean(train_examples_2_2)
std = std(train_examples_2_2)
```

Yield the correct results.

However, when I run the same code several times sometimes I get an error on the line `mean = mean(train_examples_2_2)` stating:

> Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

The exact code I am concerned with is:

```
mean = mean(train_examples_2_2) % <----- error appears here
std = std(train_examples_2_2)
for i=1:size(train_examples_2_2,1)
   train_examples_2_2(i,:) = train_examples_2_2(i,:) - mean;
   train_examples_2_2(i,:) = train_examples_2_2(i,:) ./ std;
end
% end of standardisation process
```

where `train_examples_2_2` is provided by some function that I did not create nor can modify.

According to the MATLAB documentation:

> If `A` is a matrix, then `mean(A)` returns a row vector containing the
>   mean of each column.

which is what I get the first time I run the code upon opening Matlab but after that, it yields the aforementioned error.

I am using MATLAB R2018b.

I'm I making a simple mistake or could this possibly be a bug?

Thanks for taking the time to help out.

Comment: You've overshadowed the function `mean()` by naming your variable `mean`. Rename the variables `mean` and `std` and it should fix your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unlike let's say python you shouldn't/can't/mussn't re-define function names or default variables.

```
mean = mean(train_examples_2_2) % <----- error appears here
```

matlab doesn't distinguish between the callable `mean()` function and the variable ```mean``. especially confusing since indexing and calling sth is done by using round brackets.

**So....?**

call your variable sth. other than `mean`. `mean_` will already do the trick.